# Call to ls within trapped SIGUSR1 signal results in undesired shell logout

Tags: bash, signals

I am attempting to troubleshoot an example regarding bash script signal traps given during a lecture. I copy-pasted the code into a script, but my execution of it results in an undesired and unexpected logout at the end. The instructor makes no mention that this might happen, and I am under the impression that it shouldn't. However, after failing to make contact with my TAs and fellow students, I turn to you for help!

The full slide I am reviewing can be found on page 15 here: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~brewsteb/CS344Slides/3.3%20Signals.pdf

**Expected Output**:

```
Triggering a child process termination with a silent ls SIGCHLD Received!
Exiting! [1]+  Done                    sigchldtest
```

**Actual Output**:

```
Triggering a child process termination with a silent ls
os1 ~/344_operating_systems/examples 1062$ SIGCHLD Received! Exiting!
logout
```

### ---------------

The script, sigchldtest:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -m trap "echo 'Triggering a child process termination with a silent ls'; ls > /dev/null" USR1
trap "echo 'SIGCHLD Received! Exiting!'; exit 0" CHLD

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    echo "nothing" > /dev/null
done
```

Console input:

```
sigchldtest &
kill -SIGUSR1 [sigchldtest pID]
```

---

### **Steps Taken**

- Removed "ls >/dev/null" from line 3. Code executes but does not trigger the CHLD signal trap, as expected.
- Removed "exit 0" from line 4. Shell does not log out upon completion, but user must press "enter" to return to the command prompt and the script continues running in the background (not desired). Additionally, the path name should not be printed before "SIGCHLD Received!". It appears the shell prompt is being activated during the middle of my script?

```
Triggering a child process termination with a silent ls
os1 ~/344_operating_systems/examples 1010$ SIGCHLD Received! Exiting!
{USER MUST PRESS ENTER HERE}
$
```

- Attempted process in both PuTTY and Windows 10 Console, same result.
- Attempted to kill the process in another terminal per [Ferrybig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542723/ferrybig). Killing the process in the second terminal logged me out of the first one, lol!
  [image: attempting to kill process in second terminal]

*Thank you for your time!*

Comment: Could you try to kill it from a different terminal window?

Comment: Thanks Ferrybig! Still no joy, but I added the results of your suggestion to the steps taken list.